# Determining the value of the product of a matrix A with another known matrix without knowing what is the matrix A (math GRE subject test 9768 Q.43)

Tags: matrices, gre-exam

> [image]

I have given the entries of the matrix the names $a$,$b$,$c$,$\dots$,$i$, and I multiplied the matrix by the given $2$ matrices. But the problem is that I have for every $3$ entries $2$ equation in $3$ unknowns. Could anyone show me the intuition behind solving this question please?

Comment: The intuition is that if you know that $Au=a$ and $Av=b$ for some given $(u,v,a,b)$ then you know that $A(2v-u)=2b-a$ without computing $A$.

Comment: Hint: if the third vector is a linear combination of the first two, it's easy to find the product.

Comment: Hint:  write $(6,7,8)^T$ as a linear combination of the other two matrices that are being multiplied by $A$.

Comment: You can use the fact that $A(c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2) = c_1 A(v_1)+c_2 A(v_2)$ using the property of A representing a linear transformation

Comment: Again, it is not a question of doing the computation from scratch, since all you have to do is eliminate the false answers. (A) and (D) since they have a nonzero in the bottom place cannot be the correct answer. (C) would arise from $(-3,-3,-3)^t$ so that's not it. As $2(3,4,5)^t-(0,1,2)^t=(6,7,8)^t$ (B) works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, GRE Math Subject Exam questions do not require much nitty-gritty computation.  There is almost always a "trick," or some clever way of getting around computation.  In this case, it is to use the linearity of matrix multiplication:

Using the fact that matrix multiplication is linear (i.e. $A(a\vec{u} + b\vec{v}) = aA\vec{u} + bA\vec{v}$ for any scalars $a$, $b$ and any vectors $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$), we can rewrite the last vector given as a linear combination of the other two, and obtain
\begin{align*}
&\begin{pmatrix}6\\ 7\\ 8\end{pmatrix}
= -\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\2\end{pmatrix} + 2\begin{pmatrix}3\\4\\5\end{pmatrix} \\
&\quad\implies A\begin{pmatrix}6\\ 7\\ 8\end{pmatrix}
= A\left(-\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\2\end{pmatrix} + 2\begin{pmatrix}3\\4\\5\end{pmatrix}\right)
= -A\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\2\end{pmatrix} + 2A\begin{pmatrix}3\\4\\5\end{pmatrix}
= -\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} + 2\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}-1\\2\\0\end{pmatrix},
\end{align*}
which is option (B).

Answer (score 1):

If we know that $A \vec v_1 = b_1$ and $A \vec v_2 = b_2$, then for any other vector which is a linear combination of them $\vec v = \alpha \vec v_1 + \beta \vec v_2$, we know that

$$A\vec{v} = \alpha A \vec v_1 + \beta A \vec v_2.$$

In our specific case, we can search for that linear combination by finding values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that

$$\alpha \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\2\end{bmatrix} + \beta \begin{bmatrix}3\\4\\5\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}6\\7\\8\end{bmatrix}.$$

To start, we know from the top entry that $\beta =  2$. Hence the middle entry requires that $\alpha = -1$. We check the final entry just to be sure. Our values of α and β are consistent with the final entry —if they weren't, the problem wouldn't have enough information.

We have that

$$
\begin{align*}
A\left(\begin{bmatrix}6\\7\\8\end{bmatrix}\right) &=
A\left(-1 \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\2\end{bmatrix} + 2 \begin{bmatrix}3\\4\\5\end{bmatrix}\right)\\
&= -1\cdot A\left(\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\2\end{bmatrix}\right) + 2\cdot A\left( \begin{bmatrix}3\\4\\5\end{bmatrix}\right)&\text{linearity of }A\\
&= -1 \cdot \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} + 2 \cdot \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}&\text{given values of }A\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}-1\\2\\0\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}
$$

So the answer is (B).